# Micronaut Kafka Listener : How to schedule kafka consumer poll() with 15 min interval

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, micronaut-kafka

I want to poll the topic once every 15 minutes. I found out there is a way to do this in kafka-spring with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and with below configuration

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(900000);
```

Is there any similar configuration available for micronaut Kafka as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a trivial way.

As of 4.3.0, it looks like `Consumer.poll` is being called in active loop without any delays ([source](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/blob/v4.3.0/kafka/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/processor/KafkaConsumerProcessor.java#L453)).

But it looks like you can [pause the consumer](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/blob/v4.3.0/kafka/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/ConsumerRegistry.java#L99), so you might need to periodically do the pause-resume flipping in a separate job.

Caveat emptor from Kafka side: pausing the Micronaut Consumer does not interrupt the underlying `poll` (it's handled separately ([source](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-kafka/blob/v4.3.0/kafka/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/kafka/processor/KafkaConsumerProcessor.java#L446))).